# Vue doesn't know about Error.cause property

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I created a new Vue app via `npm init vue@latest` with TS only. When I try

```
const innerError = new Error("inner");
const outerError = new Error("outer", { cause: innerError });
```

somewhere in the code it doesn't know about the `cause` property, the `Error` constructor only expects 1 argument. The file *tsconfig.app.json* contains

```
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.dom.json",
  "include": ["env.d.ts", "src/**/*", "src/**/*.vue", "vite.d.ts"],
  "exclude": ["src/**/__tests__/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "baseUrl": "."
  }
}
```

and I think I have to tell Vue to use ES2022 and up. To make it work I added the lines

```
"target": "ESNext",
"lib": ["ESNext", "DOM"],
```

to `compilerOptions`. I would like to know if this is the correct fix, because Vue seems to use ES2020 by default ( https://github.com/vuejs/tsconfig/blob/main/tsconfig.dom.json#L11 ). Or are there any other ways to solve this?

Comment: The `options` argument of the Error constructor wasn't added until ES2022.  Targeting ES2022 or ESNext would indeed be the expected solution